# I use to be able to type r.id.etc now i have to type my package blah.blah.blah.r.id.etc

Tags: android

Before I could type `R.id.exit` now I have to type `com.ramos.science.R.id.exit` why?

Answer (score 1):

Check your imports, be sure that `com.ramos.science.R` is listed there.

Comment: I suspect that if you're forced to import your own R file, there's something wrong with Eclipse that should be cured by Project > Clean.  Eclipse vomits on itself from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

`R` will conflict with the `R` class from any other package. For example, if you needed to reference some `android.R.id`... then Eclipse may have automatically imported `android.R` so you could just reference it as `R`, but that would mean that any other `R` would need to be fully qualified as `com.ramos.science.R.id`....

My recommendation, and a good convention to adopt, is to use the fully qualified `R` for other packages and simply `R` for yours. So if you ever need an Android one, always do `android.R`..., and then just import your package so you can use simply `R`.

TLDR: check your imports for other R classes. If there's any that aren't your package, delete them and add yours. For other packages use the fully qualified name, e.g. android.R.id...

**EDIT**

The Android Lint tool even has a check for this:

> Checks for 'import android.R' statements, which are usually accidental
>
> Importing `android.R` is usually not intentional; it sometimes happens
>   when you use an IDE and ask it to automatically add imports at a time
>   when your project's R class it not present. Once the import is there
>   you might get a lot of "confusing" error messages because of course
>   the fields available on `android.R` are not the ones you'd expect from
>   just looking at your own `R` class.